# What is a "zip head"... or a trank and lobo, for that matter?

Tags: back-to-the-future

In "Back to the Future" part II, when taking Jennifer to her (future) home, officers describe Hill valley as

> "... nothing but a breeding ground for tranks, lo-bos and zipheads."

What's this futuristic slang meant to mean?

Comment: I would suggest that "tranks" are probably people that use tranquilisers.

Comment: Possibly names of local gangs rather than slang?

Comment: Incidentally, "ziphead" (or "zips" or "zipperheads") is Aggie slang for a senior: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_Texas_A%26M_University_terms#Z. I think it's probably unrelated, unless there was an Aggie writer involved...

Comment: A lo-bo likely refers to someone who has had a lobotomy or removal of part of the brain.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As stated in the "Futurepedia" (http://backtothefuture.wikia.com/wiki/Ziphead); a Zip Head is a drug addict. The drug? "Zip".

> "A ziphead was a type of person referred to by Officer Foley, possibly a person who was addicted to a drug known colloquially as "zip", or a person who, like a lo-bo, had done something to their brain."

---

Similarly, a lo-bo is someone who has had a brain surgery, so a cyborg of some kind- these would likely not be necessary enhancements, but "bionic implants"

> "someone who has damaged their brain (through abuse of drugs or bionic implants) equivalent to a lobotomy"

It's possible that the inspiration for this word came from other sci-fi francises, such as Star Wars. See here the picture of "Lobot", or "Lo", Lando's aide in "The Empire Strikes Back":

[image: LOBOT]

---

A Trank: someone who has taken drugs via tranquilisers.

> > "a person under the influence of chemicals. The process of using them was to be tranked.
> >     They usually were taken via tranquilization, thus the name for those using it." [sic]

Comment: Well-answered... also, good first answer, and welcome to Stack Exchange :)

Comment: A lobotomy is a real life medical term, it didn't come from Star Wars either.

Comment: This entry cites no sources for its claim other than the movie itself, but the info on the meaning doesn't come from the movie...remember that futurepedia is a wiki that can be edited by anyone, this info is probably just (plausible) speculation by some random editor.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - Yup. All just guesswork. No sources cited whatsoever.

Comment: Aargh. I'm watching people upvoting a wiki page that has zero citations. Basically it's all guesswork. I might even go and change the pages just for a laugh.

Comment: The out of universe reason for this that I am sure people know is that Zemeckis and Gale were making futuristic slang vocabulary but I can find anything to support it just some magazine articles.

Comment: @Richard to be fair it was a good first answer, yes the citations were from unproven sources, but the words make semantic sense when you think about it. As pointed out by Probst, A lobotomy is a real life medical term, and the other suggested words make sense- clipped forms of other words.

Comment: @MikasaPinata - Except that you could just as easily make a case that a zip-head is someone who's had surgery that gives them access to their brain (via a zip) or that it's someone who's had some sort of alteration that makes them see the world faster (zipping along) or that a zip-head is an updated form of "zipper-head" (e.g. an epithet for describing an Asian person). When you play the 'Internet Mad Guessing' game, that's when the madness starts.

Comment: @Richard well so far it's the only response that's been offered, so I'm taking it ;)

Answer (score 4):

[This article](http://www.slate.com/blogs/lexicon_valley/2015/10/21/_back_to_the_future_ii_slang_how_well_did_the_movie_predict_the_language.html) in Slate contains a number of solid suggestions:

> *The lo-bos described disdainfully by Officer Foley in the movie take
>   this a step further: They’re “hobos,” but with the derogatory syllable
>   “low” swapped in for extra abjection. And within the world of BTTF,
>   lo-bo shares a resonance with low-res, a shortening of “low
>   resolution” that figuratively conjures something shoddy or downscale.
>   (In a computer-saturated age, poor quality images are more than
>   technically flawed—they’re morally repugnant.) Then there’s garbed,
>   wrong or mixed-up, redolent of both garbled and, more distantly,
>   garbage. (Congratulations, Zemeckis, for semi-accurately predicting
>   the ascent of garb, as in “That song is hot garb”!) Trank, of course,
>   is a perfectly sensible shortening of tranquilizer, and an apt term
>   for any lo-bo whose frontal lobes have been addled by sedatives.*